# Why would a completely normal loop give offset errors and maximum execution time errors?

Tags: loop

I'm too angry about this problem to see it straight anymore, so I'm guaranteed to be overlooking something simple. Please help.

Here's all my code has been stripped down to:

```
<?php

$home_gallery = new WP_Query(array(
"posts_per_page" => 2
));

if ( $home_gallery->have_posts() ) : while ( $home_gallery->have_posts() ) : 

//the_post();

//if (get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "_is_front_page_gallery", true) == "true") {
    //the_content();
    //exit;
//}

endwhile;
?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Trying to run this code on the front page of my WordPress site has causes my CPU to spike, my fan to run hot, and one of two errors to surface. Either I get a long string of "Offset = 10" errors (can't recreate that one right this minute so I can't copy/paste) or more recently I'm just getting this:

> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded

Any ideas anyone has I would be happy to hear. It's running on my localhost and has worked fine up until this afternoon. .

The problem seems very similar to this one: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/43564/repetitive-error-maximum-execution-has-exceeded-30-secs

which was closed for being unhelpful. :(

Comment: It gets stranger. I removed references to `$home_gallery` in both `have_posts()` calls, to see if a standard loop would even work. Still getting the maximum 30 seconds exceeded error. This is a file called `content-front.php` that is getting called using the `get_template_part()` function called on index.php

Comment: There's nothing in the code you posted that is at all unusual. The answer is probably in the context of the `index.php` file if you've already confirmed that a normal loop in a different theme runs OK on your WP installation. For example, are you calling that template part from within another loop? Etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured this out. It's simple, too.

As I posted it, that loop would never finish because there's nothing advancing the counter inside the while loop.

But if I uncomment my fairly normal-looking code and run it, it still wouldn't close, because I'm not advancing the *specific Query object's counter*. When you run `the_post()`, it advances the counter inside the global loop object and sets the global $post object, which is what will be run when you call functions like `the_title()` and others. So you'd run through every post in the database, because though my custom `$home_gallery` query object only had 5 posts, the global loop has all the posts in it.

In other words, since I didn't specifically run `$home_gallery->the_post();`, everything exploded.

Hope this helps someone else.